Can negative values next to bar charts in tornado diagram be shown as positive (no minus before values) in R?
I have this table:

head(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado)

               Usluge   Troskovi Populacija lab_hjust
1           Poseta OP  925549213         EM      -0.1
2    Poseta neurologu  324400906         EM      -0.1
3 Poseta specijalisti  636457799         EM      -0.1
4         Hitna pomoć 1322546400         EM      -0.1
5                  MR 1234011455         EM      -0.1
6                  CT  194259737         EM      -0.1


tail(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado)

                       Usluge   Troskovi Populacija lab_hjust
31           Bolničko lečenje  -39290250         HM       1.1
32             Inj. botulinum  -18000000         HM       1.1
33                       TENS  -80296480         HM       1.1
34            Akutna terapija -122609324         HM       1.1
35     Profilaktička terapija   -9818482         HM       1.1
36 Blokada okcipitalnog nerva  -32509440         HM       1.1

T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Troskovi <- abs(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Troskovi) * ifelse(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Populacija == "EM", 1, -1)
T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado

# compute right or left justification
T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$lab_hjust <- ifelse(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Populacija == "EM", -0.1, 1.1)

# order factor levels by value
T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Usluge <- reorder(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Usluge, T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado$Troskovi, FUN = \(x) sum(abs(x))) 
T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado

and a code for making a tornado diagram:
ggplot(T_Zbirna_sa_BlokadomON_za_Tornado, aes(x = Troskovi, y = Usluge, fill = Populacija)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = format(floor(Troskovi), big.mark="."),   
      # map `hjust` to computed hjust 
      hjust = lab_hjust,
    ), 
    size = 5
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    #label = scales::comma,
    # expansion to accommodate labels
    expand = expansion(mult = 0.25),
    labels=human_numbers
  ) +
  # set axis label 
  labs(title="...\n",
       x ="...",
       y = "...") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0F6D96", "#1C92F4")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=15), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.title=element_text(size=15),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5))

Everything works perfectly and the graph I get is great, but I need values next to negative bar charts shown as positive. Is it possible to do so?
The graph looks like this (I've removed the labels from the picture for this purpose):

So, these values on the left side of zero should not precede with the minus sign. Can anyone help me?

I think this could be as simple as using the absolute value label = format( abs( floor(Troskovi) ), big.mark=".") in your geom_text?

Thank you so much for the quick response! It looks great now!
